NavigationStack with @Observable won't works
do you know how to ensure continuous navigation in our app from the main screen to screen 1 and from screen 1 to screen 2 using append on NavigationPath? Unfortunately, in my example, it only works for one step and then stops being observed. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Step to reproduce:

Tap "Go to view1" button
Tap "Go to view 2" button

Expected:

User see "View 2" text
I don't won't use EnvironmentObject if no needed

import SwiftUI

@Observable @MainActor
final class MainClass {
    
    public enum Destination: Hashable {
        case view1(Class1)
        case view2(Class2)
    }
    
    var path: [Destination]
    
    init(path: [Destination] = []) {
        self.path = path
    }
}

@Observable @MainActor
final class Class1: Hashable {
    
    var path: [MainClass.Destination]
    
    init(path: [MainClass.Destination] = []) {
        self.path = path
    }
    
    
    nonisolated static func == (lhs: Class1, rhs: Class1) -> Bool {
        ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
    }

    nonisolated func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self))
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @Bindable var model: Class1
    var body: some View {
        Button("View 1") {
            model.path.append(.view2(Class2(path: model.path)))
        }
    }
}

@Observable @MainActor
final class Class2: Hashable {
    
    var path: [MainClass.Destination]
    
    init(path: [MainClass.Destination] = []) {
        self.path = path
    }
    
    nonisolated static func == (lhs: Class2, rhs: Class2) -> Bool {
        ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
    }

    nonisolated func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self))
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Bindable var model: Class2
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
    }
}

@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {
    @Bindable var mainClass = MainClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $mainClass.path) {
            Button("Go to view 1") {
                mainClass.path.append(.view1(.init(path: mainClass.path)))
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationDestination(for: MainClass.Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case let .view1(model):
                    View1(model: model)
                case let .view2(model):
                    View2(model: model)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


You have two separate path variables that don't know about each other in Class1 and Class2. For the path to work properly, you essentially need a shared variable passed throughout the Stack.
I would move the path out of the model and into the view. So like this:
import SwiftUI

enum ViewType {
    case view1, view2
}

struct View1: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 1")
        NavigationLink("Go to view 2", value: ViewType.view2)
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
    }
}

@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Button("Go to view 1") {
                path.append(ViewType.view1)
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationDestination(for: ViewType.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case .view1:
                    View1(path: $path)
                case ViewType.view2:
                    View2(path: $path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Note the use of @Binding - this lets other views observe the path and make changes to it.
You can add more views to the enum if needed, set the path to NavigationPath() to go back to the root view, create a variable in the enum if you still need to pass in the model. Here's a pretty thorough rundown of NavigationStack that was helpful to me: https://www.swiftyplace.com/blog/better-navigation-in-swiftui-with-navigation-stack

Hey, cool, but what I mean is to separate the navigation from the view. In this case, we are keeping the logic inside the view, and if we want, for example, to add additional actions when pressing a button, we have a split. The article you sent me shows NavigationStateManager, which is nice, but I would like to use it inside a class.

@miltenkot out of curiosity, why do you want to keep the navigation inside classes instead of in the view? Keeping it in classes (especially multiple classes) will likely make it more complicated to pass the state around.

Hey, in my opinion, firstly it helps with testing, secondly with deep links, and thirdly, I use this solution only for stack-based navigation, whereas inside the view, I create tree-based navigation locally, so the problem of being 'complicated' doesn't occur in my opinion.

Hi all I finally found solution based on pointfree https://github.com/pointfreeco/syncups/tree/main.
Here is the code if anyone is interested. If somebody see any issue there please comment :)
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUINavigation
import DependenciesMacros

@Observable @MainActor
final class MainClass {
    
    public enum Destination: Hashable {
        case view1(Class1)
        case view2(Class2)
    }
    
    var path: [Destination] {
        didSet { self.bind() }
    }
    
    init(path: [Destination] = []) {
        self.path = path
    }
    
    func next() {
        path.append(.view1(Class1()))
    }
    
    private func bind() {
        for destination in self.path {
            switch destination {
            case let .view1(model):
                bindView1(model: model)
            case let .view2(model):
                bindView2(model: model)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func bindView1(model: Class1) {
        model.onNextTapped = { [weak model, weak self] in
            guard let model else { return }
            self?.path.append(.view2(Class2()))
        }
    }
    
    func bindView2(model: Class2) {
        model.onEndTapped = { [weak model, weak self] in
            guard let model else { return }
            self?.path = []
        }
    }
}

@Observable @MainActor
final class Class1: HashableObject {
    
    @DependencyEndpoint
    @ObservationIgnored
    var onNextTapped: () -> Void = {  }
    
    func next() {
        onNextTapped()
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @Bindable var model: Class1
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Go to view 2") {
            model.next()
        }
    }
}

@Observable @MainActor
final class Class2: HashableObject {
    
    @DependencyEndpoint
    @ObservationIgnored
    var onEndTapped: () -> Void = {  }
    
    func next() {
        onEndTapped()
    }
    
}

struct View2: View {
    @Bindable var model: Class2
    var body: some View {
        Button("View 2") {
            model.onEndTapped()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {
    @Bindable var mainClass = MainClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $mainClass.path) {
            Button("Go to view 1") {
                mainClass.next()
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationDestination(for: MainClass.Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case let .view1(model):
                    View1(model: model)
                case let .view2(model):
                    View2(model: model)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

